# A smart host in Amazon SES

Tags: office365, amazon-ses, office365connectors

I need to implement a smart host relay with some added functionality. The emails are coming from Office 365. The recipients of the emails aren't in my control, and may be any valid email address.

I'm trying to configure a Office 365 connector, pointing the smart host server to be: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. As far as I can see, Office 365 doesn't let me to set credentials for authenticated SMTP (am I wrong?).

In Amazon SES, I'm setting up a rule to store the email in a S3 bucket, and also call a lambda function.

However, with such settings, Amazon SES is unable to direct the email to my rule, as nothing in the communication from Office 365 tells him to destine the email to my direction. How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this old, unanswered question today when doing a search of my own. I'm figuring you probably have this resolved by now, but one issue above is that you're trying to send email to their mail client interface (email-smtp) instead of the SMTP gateway interface. Try instead directing your connector to inbound.eu-west1-1.amazonaws.com and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Huh, this didn't (or doesn't anymore) seem to work. It couldn't find that url...

Comment: Found it; inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.

However, SES doesn't seem to support outbound rules so this direction seems to be a dead-end for implementing intended OP functionality.

Comment: Here a link to the proper end points:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html